# Getting ysql_num_shards_per_tserver in YugabyteDB using YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We are using client driver(sql package - database/sql - pkg.go.dev) and YugabyteDB 2.8.3.
There is a variable `ysql_num_shards_per_tserver` configured with every TSERVER.
We would like to determine hash ranges of each tablet based on:

```
tablets= ysql_num_shards_per_tserver * num_tservers
```

But, before running the `SELECT` query, we need to get the number of tablets for a table.
Example:
For a table with 48 tablets,
first hash range is [0, 1395)
second hash range is [1395, 2730)
etc.

What is the GoLang API in client driver to retrieve value of `ysql_num_shards_per_tserver` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can’t query the `ysql_num_shards_per_tserver` gflag from the client layer. But you can hardcode it in your configuration because you do the same on the YugabyteDB cluster.

Since it’s fixed at configuration time when starting yb-tserver, you can hardcode it in your configuration too.

Another way, the tablets, and their (encoded) ranges can be seen using yb-admin:

```
yugabyte=# create table t (id int primary key) split into 4 tablets;
yugabyte=# insert into t values (1);
yugabyte=# insert into t values (2);
yugabyte=# insert into t values (3);
yugabyte=# insert into t values (4);
```

```
[vagrant@yb-1 ~]$ yb-admin list_tablets ysql.yugabyte t
Tablet-UUID Range Leader-IP Leader-UUID
d3ab946a8fdb438ea7686470e55eee53 partition_key_start: "" partition_key_end: "?\377" yb-1.local:9100 7922bc6371ef4d2d8082a2882a1dfafa
d1b63e3ac36d46128d028572135ad621 partition_key_start: "?\377" partition_key_end: "\177\376" yb-1.local:9100 7922bc6371ef4d2d8082a2882a1dfafa
8f1229413df84560bd531d8ee8ff88e0 partition_key_start: "\177\376" partition_key_end: "\277\375" yb-1.local:9100 7922bc6371ef4d2d8082a2882a1dfafa
457d357288134020b1e5c297be86a5ca partition_key_start: "\277\375" partition_key_end: "" yb-1.local:9100 7922bc6371ef4d2d8082a2882a1dfafa
```